# Does the A220-300 have krueger flaps or are all of its leading-edge highlift devices slats?

Tags: flaps, slats, airbus-a220

They look like slats to me, but I could be wrong. I'm asking because I know the 737, a very similar airplane, has inboard krueger flaps.

Also, what number of slats/krueger flaps does it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All are slats. [Here is one taking off.](https://youtu.be/l6qjpCMyPzY?t=187) and a [better view](https://youtu.be/g154c72heXU?t=973) of one in the air. It looks like there are as many as four sections but they all extend and retract together.

[image]